# How to set library list using cwbx.dll and AS400System class from C# to IBM i (iSeries)

Tags: c#, dll, odbc, rpgle

I use client access driver to make sql calls to IBM i (an iSeries).  When using the driver I can specify a library list that will be used when issuing sql commands/functions.

I now need to access an iSeries from C# and make calls to CL/RPGLE programs.  I found that I can create an AS400System object after adding a reference to cwbx.dll.  However, I am not sure how to set a library list and am having trouble finding documentation on cwbx.dll.  Has anyone else been able to use this object to set a library list?

Comment: Don't go down the change library list path it's not a good programming practice.  Like how many times to you programatically change the java path?  Just start with the correct library list.  It would be setup in the connection or with the userid you are connecting to the as400 with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this [doc](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_i_software_access_pdf_dataxfer.pdf): "CWBX.DLL (The Programmatic interface) allows to do Data Transfer operations programmatically"

That's not what you're wanting to do.

You probably want to use the [DB2 for i .NET provider](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows/dotnet.html).

Documentation for the provider is installed when you select "Programmer's Toolkit" during the IBm iAccess installation.

Did a little more digging, documentation for CWBX.DLL can be found in:
**C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Client Access\MRI2924\cwbx.hlp**

It doesn't appear that you can manipulate the library list for a command.  Only a data transfer via the DatabaseUserLibraryList object.

The recommended way to call RPGLE / CL from .NET would be call them as an SQL stored procedure.  Technically, given the object based nature of the OS, every *PGM (or procedure in a *SRVPGM) object on the box is already a stored procedure and can be called implicitly using the SQL call command.  However,  it's beneficial and recommended to explicitly define the RPG / CL interface to the DB using the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement with the `EXTERNAL NAME` clause as shown below.

example from this [article](http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/ibmi/developer/rpg/rpg_stored_procedures/)

Assume you have a *PGM named CUSTINFO, with the following *program* interface (aka *ENTRY PLIST)

```
D CustInfo         PI
D  CustNo                    5P 0
D  Name                     15A
D  City                     25A
D  State                     2A 
D  Active                    1P 0
```

Where CustNo is input, the rest of the parms are used as output.  Then you can explicitly define this program as an SQL stored procedure simply by running the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCustInfo    
 (IN CustNo DEC (5,0), OUT Name CHAR (15), OUT City CHAR(25), 
 OUT St CHAR(2), OUT Act DEC(1,0))
 EXTERNAL NAME MYLIB/CUSTINFO   
 LANGUAGE RPGLE 
 PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL
```

- note I used the term "program interface".  Technically it's the *entry point or mainline procedure interface*

Comment: Thanks, I have found this doc as well.  One of the things the dll allows is Data Transfer, but the dll allows for calls into the iSeries.  I've successfully done this, but can't figure out how to set the librarly list.  I have looked at the .NET provider but it only provides access to SQL, not calls to CL/RPGLE programs.

Comment: OK, I see some non-IBM posts on the net about using CWBX.DLL that way.  New to me.  Technically, every *PGM object on the IBM i is a stored procedure and can be implicitly called using the SQL `CALL` statement.  However, it's usually best to explicitly define the interface to the *PGM by using the SQL `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement with the `EXTERNAL NAME` clause.  Have you considered going that route so that you're using a documented interface...rather than the undocumented features of CWBX.DLL?

Comment: Yes sir, I did think about going that route.  However, I thought it would me messier than using the AS400System in cwbx.  Why do you say it is undocumented, the .hlp (.chm file in my case) file contains all the necessary info regarding the objects/methods/enums involved?  I think you are correct regarding the inability in setting up a library list.  However, I noticed a way I can do what I need.  I 1)  First call a CL program to setup the library list then 2)  Call the RPGLE program I need that requires the library list is setup.

Comment: Yeah, found the documentation after posting my comment...so rather than undocumented...lets call it outdated.

Comment: Okay, so using this dll is antiquated.  AND I didn't actually realize I could use CALL to call RPG and CL programs.  Thanks for this enlightenment.  If using ODBC, how would I get values for, say, 2 variables that I sent using call (ie CALL myprog(invar, outvar1, outvar2)?  Do I have to wrap the procedure in an sql function?

Comment: You're not really "wrapping" the RPG/CL in an SQL procedure.  You're just defining the RPG/CL interface with (or to)  SQL.  I've added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Asked and answered, I know.  But here's my answer to the question posed.

The command `CHGLIBL LIBL(<space-separated list of libraries>)` in a cwbx.Command call will force the AS/400 user library list to be the list needed.  It also forces the library list to be in the same order as specified.

Also, IMO, the CWBX APIs provide more error details than the SQL interface when calling AS/400 programs (especially CL's).